# Why does the SHA512 code include numbers ending in ULL?

Tags: cryptography, source

[The sha512-blocs.c file](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/crypto_ops_builder/sha512-blocks.c) contains five blocks like these:

> ```
> F(w0 ,0x428a2f98d728ae22ULL)
> F(w1 ,0x7137449123ef65cdULL)
> F(w2 ,0xb5c0fbcfec4d3b2fULL)
> F(w3 ,0xe9b5dba58189dbbcULL)
> F(w4 ,0x3956c25bf348b538ULL)
> F(w5 ,0x59f111f1b605d019ULL)
> F(w6 ,0x923f82a4af194f9bULL)
> F(w7 ,0xab1c5ed5da6d8118ULL)
> F(w8 ,0xd807aa98a3030242ULL)
> F(w9 ,0x12835b0145706fbeULL)
> F(w10,0x243185be4ee4b28cULL)
> F(w11,0x550c7dc3d5ffb4e2ULL)
> F(w12,0x72be5d74f27b896fULL)
> F(w13,0x80deb1fe3b1696b1ULL)
> F(w14,0x9bdc06a725c71235ULL)
> F(w15,0xc19bf174cf692694ULL)
> ```

```
EXPAND
```

I assume these are hexadecimal digits, but I don't see where the second variable *k* of this function is declared. Does ULL have a special meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer by googling in order to formulate a somewhat intelligent question: [ULL means Unsigned Long Long integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809292/ull-suffix-on-a-numeric-literal).